# Magento 2.2.1 Product Import Not Updating Assigned Categories

Tags: magento2, import, magento2.2

When updating my products via the add/update import process, the assigned product categories are not being updated.  If I update by selecting "replace", it works.  Example

Product-A currently has the categories of "Shirts/Blue,Shorts/Blue"

I want to remove Shorts/Blue, so in my csv file, I have

Product-A,"Shirts/Blue"  (all other fields intentionally left out of this post, but they are in my file)

Other fields are being updated just fine.  Its only the category field that isnt removing previously assigned categories.

If I assign a new category, it assigns it, but still doesnt remove the previously assigned categories.  Example:  If my file has

Product-A,"Shirts/Blue,Pants/Blue"

After import and reindexing, Product-A now has Shirts/Blue,Shorts/Blue,Pants/Blue categories assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a feature.  Awful:  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7930